# Codeignite can't delete imags and files from the server?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to delete dynamically my selected images from server with php and Codeigniter?
it I see just a blank page but my images are not deleted.
I am new to development of Codeigniter applications please help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced the same problem before and I did these steps and it was fixed.

1-check your folder permission and make sure you have the permission on the server to delete a file.

2-if you used base_url() as the base path for example:

```
$image_path = base_url()."uploads/image_name.jpeg";
unlink($image_path);
```

remove base_url() and use FCPATH, APPPATH, BASEPATH

for example:

```
$image_path = FCPATH."uploads/".$file_name;
unlink($image_path);
```

this will solve your problem.